# Issue with react click event on IOS

Tags: reactjs, onclick, ontouchstart

i am having an issue with a React delete modal ONLY on iOS (it works very good on other devices)– the buttons don't respond properly to touch events.

Tried various solutions, including modifying touch event handlers and CSS. Any suggestions on how to make buttons responsive to touch ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.